# High frequency data reading from Raspberry

Tags: gpio, windows-iot

Is it possible to organize the reading of data from GPIO with high and precise frequency (up to 200 kHz) in win10 IoT?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Talking multiple pins at the same time (parallel) oder just one (serial, e.g. dedicated serial pins, UART or SPI) (if it matters)?